# NTLM implementation in JavaScript with POST method

Tags: javascript, ntlm

I searched a lot but did not find suitable answer to implement my project code using NTLM in JavaScript. I want to send POST method with dataType as json type but every time I am getting 401 - Unauthorized message.

I referred the link https://github.com/erlandranvinge/ntlm.js/tree/master to download ntlm.js and implemented as described but no success.

Please help if anybody knows about it.

The provided ntlm code is below:

```
Ntlm.setCredentials('domain', 'username', 'password');
var url = 'http://myserver.com/secret.txt';

if (Ntlm.authenticate(url)) {
    performPostOperation();
    // => My super secret message stored on server.
}
```

Inside the `performPostOperation()` function:

```
$.ajax({
    "method" : 'POST',
    "url" : URL,
    "data": {data}
    "dataType":"json",
    "withCredentials":true,
    credentials:"include",
    beforeSend:function(xhr){
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('domain', 'DOMAINNAME');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('username', username);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('password', password);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
    }
})
```

Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: why are you setting all that stuff in the header? The example in the github page does nothing of the sort. Also in theory you've already authenticated using NTLM, the browser will now take care of including the access token generated by that authentication process (note, access token, not username and password, you used those the first time in the ntlm.authenticate call). Does it work if you remove all that junk, does it work if you use plain XHR like the example in the github page?

Comment: P.S. there's no `credentials` or   `withCredentials` options in jquery ajax, not sure where you got that from. Check the docs: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ . Maybe you meant `xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
   }`

Comment: Another point `xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');` ...this is a **server-side** header. It makes no sense to set this in the request. The server decides which origins it accepts CORS requests from, not the client, otherwise what would be the point of such a restriction, do you suppose, if the client can just allow itself access? Potentially you need to set up the CORS headers properly on the **server**, if your ajax request is cross domain.

Comment: Another thing: `"url" : URL`...is this a different variable? Because `URL` is not the same variable as `url` specified earlier in the code. Is your ajax request visiting the same URL you authenticated with NTLM, or not? Because if not, that could be a problem.

Comment: Lastly is your server definitely configured to accept NTLM auth? It may not be, if it only like Kerberos requests. You should double-check. Any I hope this isn't an important user account because now everyone who can read your Javascript code in the browser (which, in theory, is everyone) has got the username and password details.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson, Your response is really helpful. Now come to one by one what you have asked:

Comment: 1. I tried a lot but it was not passed for POST method. After reading more details in different websites, I removed all and just kept the below attributes in headers:   `xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
   xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization');
   xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'WWW-Authenticate');`
   xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');

Comment: 2. You are right about the options for ajax. It is  worth reading the link: [api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax]. 3. I removed     xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); from request set and I double checked that target server is receiving NTLM authentication. 4. the URL value (url) that is authenticating and visiting during POST method is same. I looked at the ntlm.js and in authentoicate function, the request.setRequestHeader() is not working, (correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: `request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'NTLM ' + msg1.toBase64());
    request.send(null);
    var response = request.getResponseHeader('WWW-Authenticate');` challenge is empty as response is null, `var challenge = Ntlm.getChallenge(response);`. Other part of this I noticed in Fiddler that when I send the transaction, I first get 204 respond code (with OPTION method) then I get 401 - unauthorized.. if you know other api for ntlm authentication using ajax call with POST method (and example), would be much appreciate.

Comment: "xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST'); xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization'); xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'WWW-Authenticate');"....all of these are headers which the **server** must set when it sends its response. You, as the client, can't set them. Well, you can, but it's meaningless and doesn't achieve anything. The server will not act on them when it sees them in your request.

Comment: It's hard to tell if you have an NTLM issue or a CORS issue